# Rails 5 how to load relations model structure with new Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have Create and Edit form powered by Rails and VueJs (not SPA). I need a consistent JSON structure for both Create and Edit form.

```
class VisitReport < ApplicationRecord

  has_one: visit_report_doctor
  has_many :visit_report_visitors

end
```

At Edit Form (visit_reports/1/edit)

Controller

```
def edit
  @visit_report = VisitReport.find(params[:id])
end
```

HTML

```
<%= @visit_report.to_json(:include => { :visit_report_doctor => {}, :visit_report_visitors => {} }) %>
```

I will get this JSON:

```
id: 1,
visit_report_visitors: [],
visit_report_doctor: {
    id: 14,
    visit_report_id: 1,
    name: 'Doctor G'
}
```

At Create Form, new record

Controller

```
def new
  @visit_report = VisitReport.new
end
```

HTML

```
<%= @visit_report.to_json(:include => { :visit_report_doctor => {}, :visit_report_visitors => {} }) %>
```

I got this JSON object (notice that visit_report_doctor is not included in the JSON which is what I want)

However empty relations of has_many visit_report_visitors is included:

```
id: null,
visit_report_visitors: [],
```

Question is, how do I force load the visit_report_doctor relations when the key is null so that my JSON structure is consistent for both New and Edit form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also have applications using VueJS, a great tool for consistent JSON (also for better readability and structure on Rails side) is [ActiveModelSerializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). This helps you keep a consistent JSON structure for your models as well as not clog up your controllers with what is supposed to be the "view" part of the application.

Comment: thanks I will take a look into this gem and others alternative